# jetty server log request body

Tags: servlets, jackson, jetty

```
RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
Slf4jRequestLog requestLog = new CustomSlf4jRequestLog();
requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```

Slf4jRequestLog is only logging request method, url and date, and response status code and bytes written.
I definitely want to log body for my PUT/POST requests.
I derived CustomSlf4jRequestLog from Slf4jRequestLog and I tried:

```
public void log(Request request, Response response) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("RequestBody: ");
        try {
            LOG.info("BODY SIZE: " + request.getContentLength());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            LOG.info(sb.toString());
```

Unfortunately no body is printed out as it is already processed by handler?

Is it possible to get body of request here?

(I really care about body because I have JsonProvider and I want to see a whole body of request when Json fails to parse data) Or when my app fails I want to see what caused that without adding logging for each input request.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet spec getting in your way here.

The actual servlet that is processing the request has already read the request body, rending further reads from `request.getInputStream()` invalid (you are at EOF)

If you want to capture the request body, you'll need to create a custom Servlet `Filter`, and then wrap the `HttpServletRequest`, overriding the `getInputStream()` **AND** `getReader()` methods with your own implementations that make a copy of the data that was read.

Then its up to you to determine what you want to do with that copy of the request body content.

*or*

You can just use a network capture utility like Wireshark to see what the request body was.  Even if you use HTTPS, you can configure Wireshark with your server certificate to inspect encrypted conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The logger is calling **getInputStream()** on the same request again. You are not allowed to read the same data twice. Yo should create a **ServletRequestWrapper** to make a copy of the body of the request.